# Is it possible to use FormObjects and FormFunction in a stand-alone notebook?

Tags: programming, user-interface

I have been looking at the [`FormObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormObject.html) and [`FormFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html).  Can `FormObject` and `FormFunction` be used without `CloudDeploy`?

Are there any examples of using `FormObject` or `FormFunction` that show how a submit would be done for a given `FormObject`?

Should submit be implemented as a Button control?

Comment: I.m.o. `FormFunction` is designed for cloud deployment. Even `form[]` is meant only for a quick check/preview. To have full control just use `DialogInput`/`Input` and friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a form definition:

```
ff = FormFunction[FormObject[<|"x" -> "Number"|>], #x^2 &]
```

Now watch the `[]` after the `ff`, this launches the form and waits for input and shows a submit button

```
ff[]
```

If you want put a value in the form without showing a submit button:

```
ff["x" -> 9]
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: pvanbijen - Thank you very much!  This is very useful !

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Wolfram Language Documentation has only one example on how to read data from inside a notebook using a `FormFunction` and it is not easy for a newcomer to notice or understand how input is read and what is the form of output.

For the example above, it is not necessary to use `FormObject` as the first argument of `FormFunction` and you don't even have to pass a `Function` as the second argument. A single argument with a list of rules representing fields and types is sufficient. Therefore you can :

1. **Construct the form**

   ```
   twofields = FormFunction[{"x" -> "Number"},{"y"->"String"}];
   ```
2. **Complete the form**

   ```
   twofields[]
   ```

[image]

```
    Output= <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> "three"|>
```

Comment: Am I really the only one who has print to console settings and `form[]` displays in `MassagesNotebook`?

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to tweak the appearance of field boxes, e.g. width and height, font size, that will be great.